# Bounds for the sup norm for matrices

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have a matrix $A = [a_{ij}]$ of size $n$ by $m$. We define a norm

$$ ||A|| = \max \{ |a_{ij}|: i=1..n, j=1..m \} $$

If $A$ is n by m and $B$ is m by p, we want to check the following estimate:

$$ || A \cdot B || \leq m ||A|| ||B|| $$

${\bf ATTEMPT}$

I believe the key is in the triangle inequality. if we let $C = A\cdot B$, then a general entry of $C$ is $c_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^m a_{ik} b_{kj} $ Suppose the maximum entry in C occurs at the indeces $i = i_0$ and $j=j_0$. Then,

$$||A\cdot B|| = \left| \sum_{k=1}^m a_{i_0k} b_{kj_0} \right| \leq \sum |a_{i_0k} b_{kj_0}| \leq \sum ||A|| ||B|| = ||A|| ||B|| \sum 1 = m ||A||||B|| $$

as desired. Is this proof rigorous enough, or does it need more work? Thanks

Comment: It doesn't need any more work

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: As **Aditya Dwivedi** said, it needs no more work: what you have is a correct argument, though I’d prefer to see the bounds on all of the summations, not just the first one. Alternatively, instead of picking out $i_0$ and $j_0$ you could note that $$|c_{ij}|=\left|\sum_{k=1}^ma_{ik}b_{kj}\right|\le\sum_{k=1}^m|a_{ik}b_{kj}|=\sum_{k=1}^m|a_{ik}||b_{kj}|\le\sum_{k=1}^m\|A\|\|B\|=m\|A\|\|B\|$$ for each entry $c_{ij}$ in $C$, so $$\|C\|=\max\{|c_{ij}|:i=1,\ldots,m\text{ and }j=1,\ldots,p\}\le m\|A\|\|B\|\,.$$ It’s the same idea presented a little differently; the choice is a matter of taste.